# Creating row-based Boolean mask from column-based Boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas

I am unsure how best to create a row-based Boolean mask from column-based Boolean mask.

I am trying to extract defined length (e.g. 1,2,3 etc.) positive (or negative) run sequences from 'B' for one 'SN' into a new mask.

I have now implemented a simple mask (below) and on top of that a complicated for-loop with several if-statements to do this. Is there some more elegant way to create mask-on-mask in Pandas?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "SN" : ["66", "66", "77", "77", "77", "77", "77"], 
    "B" : [-1, 1, 2, 3, 1, -1, 1]
})
mask = df['B'] > 0
```

The output with simple mask is

```
   SN  B
0  66 -1
1  66  1
2  77  2
3  77  3
4  77  1
5  77 -1
6  77  1

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
```

The desired output is

```
defined_min_length = 2

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False

defined_min_length = 3

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False

defined_min_length = 4

0    False
1    False 
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
```

Edit: Try to fix question's ambiguity. The key point is the "defined length". E.g. in the example defined lenght = 4 would yield all False as there is no positive run with length 4 in the data frame for any equipment (with same 'SN').

Edit 2: I reformulate the original question. Adding variable defined_min_length to indicate the desired run-length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
def ExtractPositiveSequence(df,defined_min_length):

    group_s= df.groupby(['SN',df['B'].lt(0).cumsum()])['B']

    return ( group_s.transform('size')
                    .sub(group_s.transform('first')
                                .lt(0)
                                .astype(int))
                    .ge(defined_min_length) 
                    .mul(df['B'].gt(0))
           )
```

---

```
ExtractPositiveSequence(df,2)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

ExtractPositiveSequence(df,3)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: B, dtype: bool


ExtractPositiveSequence(df,4)


0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

---

**Note:**

- remove `.mul(df['B'].gt(0))`, if you want to include the initial negative before a positive sequence.
- **To search for negative sequences:** `ExtractPositiveSequence(df.assign(B=df['B'].mul(-1)), n)`

Comment: this works for defined lenght = 1, but I don't understand how it'd work for e.g. defined length =  4. In this case all mask2 values should be False.

Comment: Great! I had to reformulate, as I understood that the original question was not good.

Comment: I think I now understand your question. I have updated my solution

Comment: This is it! I managed to figure out the same for negative values from this.

Comment: Just one minor detail: what's the logic behind this statement : "remove .mul(df['B'].gt(0)), if you want to include the initial negative before a positive sequence." Either way it has no effect on the output [F,F,T,T,T,F,F].

Comment: test with `defined_min_length` equal to 1